# M1 CE, paypal exception "PayPal NVP gateway errors"

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-express, exception, paypal-standard

With the standard checkout process sometimes paypal get the money but magento dont' close the order ( making the cusotmer pay many times the order)
In some orders we see 2 times rows with the sames sku
the customer tell us that have many stock error.

it's Magento 1.9.2.2, hosted on Google Cloud with multiple frontends and a dedicated mysql & admin instance..

> exception 'Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_ProcessableException' with message 'PayPal NVP gateway errors: This transaction couldn't be completed. Please redirect your customer to PayPal (#10486: This transaction couldn't be completed). Correlation ID: 72b838c934484. Version: 72.0.' in /path/to/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php:1062
>   Stack trace:
>    /path/to/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php(1008): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->_handleCallErrors(Array)
>    /path/to/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php(643): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->call('DoExpressChecko...', Array)
>    /path/to/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express.php(581): Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp->callDoExpressCheckoutPayment()
>    /path/to/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express.php(377): Mage_Paypal_Model_Express->_placeOrder(Object(Webmu_DisableAutoInvoice_Model_Sales_Order_Payment), '81.62')
>    /path/to/magento/public_html/app/code/community/Webmu/DisableAutoInvoice/Model/Sales/Order/Payment.php(57): Mage_Paypal_Model_Express->capture(Object(Webmu_DisableAutoInvoice_Model_Sales_Order_Payment), '81.62')
>    /path/to/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(348): Webmu_DisableAutoInvoice_Model_Sales_Order_Payment->capture(NULL)
>    /path/to/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(898): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->place()
>    /path/to/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1116): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_placePayment()
>    /path/to/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105): call_user_func(Array)
>    /path/to/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks()
>    /path/to/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
>    /path/to/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
>    /path/to/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php(599): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
>    /path/to/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout->place('EC-2T656796LX81...')
>    /path/to/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract->placeOrderAction()
>    /path/to/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('placeOrder')
>    /path/to/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>    /path/to/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>    /path/to/magento/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>    /path/to/magento/public_html/index.php(91): Mage::run('default', 'store')
>    {main}

Comment: @philwinkle any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've faced this a number of times at Something Digital. Sometimes the Nvp exceptions aren't the root cause. They're likely raised with exceptions happening elsewhere and the payments objects using Exceptions as routing behavior.

Here are the most likely causes:

- Observers listening to `sales_order_place_after` are failing
- Observers listening to `sales_order_payment_place_end`
- Issues with IPN deadlocking the order place
- Model load in loop causing deadlocking on sales order tables

Any of these could be caused by an extension or custom code. A bit of an audit would have to be conducted to find out the root cause for sure.

To that end Magento 1.9+ did a great job of solving some of the common deadlock issues. Seeing as you're on 1.9.2 this is not the likely cause. Again, I know this isn't a concrete answer but without further investigation hopefully this sets you off in a good path.

Comment: this is actually a great answer, since from several possibility at least now i can have some direction to follow. thank you @philwinkle!